# How to remove strings in list from another list?

Tags: c#, string, list, duplicates, removeall

I have 2 list which names are listA and listB.

I want to remove strings in listB which are in listA, but I want to do this in this way:

if listA contains: "bar", "bar", "bar", "foo"
and listB contains : "bar"

it removes only 1 bar and the result will be:
"bar", "bar", "foo"

the code I wrote removes all "bar":

```
List<string> result = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: Does retaining some of the original list's order matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to remove it one by one:

```
foreach (var word in listB)
    listA.Remove(word);
```

The Remove method will only remove one element at a time and is not throwing exception (but returning false) when the item is not found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can avoid the Contains call using directly IndexOf to get the position

Comment: It's inefficient, but you can make it at least use directly `listA.Remove(word)`. No need of `Contains`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var listA = new List<string>() { "bar", "bar", "bar", "foo" };
var listB = new List<string>() { "bar" };

foreach (var word in listB){
  listA.Remove(word);
}
```

Comment: This is basically a copy of the @Ian answer posted 10+ minutes before yours

Answer (score 1):

This is a faster method but it is likely to change the order of elements of first list. Steps:

- Map the listA to a `Dictionary<string, int>` (let's call it `listAMap`), where key is the element of the list and value is the total number of times that value has occurred in listA;
- Iterate through listB and for every element of listB, if that element is in the `listAMap`, reduce its count;
- Get the keys of `listMapA` using [Keys property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) of C# dictionaries, and iterate through all the keys. For every key which has positive value, add that key to another list a total of its count times. So if an entry is `"bar" -> 2`, then add "bar" twice in the new list.

Total run time of the algorithm is *O(m + n)*, where m and n are number of elements in both the original lists. It is a better running time than other approaches mentioned here which have *O(m * n)* running time. Obviously this algorithm uses more space.

---

Supportive Code for the algorithm above:

```
//Step-1: Create the dictionary...
var listAMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var listAElement in listA)
{
    listAMap.ContainsKey(listAElement) ? listAMap[listAElement]++ : listAMap.Add(listAElement, 1);
}

// Step-2: Remove the listB elements from dictionary...
foreach (var listBElement in listB)
{
    if (listAMap.Contains(listBElement)) listAMap[listBElement]--;
}

//Step-3: Create the new list from pruned dictionary...
var prunedListA = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in listAMap.Keys)
{
    if (listAMap[key] <= 0) continue;
    for (var count = 0; count < listAMap[key]; count++)
    {
        prunedListA.Add(key);
    }
}

//prunedListA contains the desired elements now.
```

Comment: I was thinking for something similar, but counting listB and then removing the items from listA tah match (and decrementing the matching count). Anyway, +1 for thinking about efficiency.

Comment: @IvanStoev: We aren't matching items in list. We are doing an O(1) lookup in a dictionary. Seriously, the solution is very simple (Not that you can give a +2 on the answer). I should've added the code too. Will do when I access SO from laptop.

Comment: @IvanStoev: The last thing that needs to be done now is that the code above be factored into a separate method so that its cleaner.

Comment: Good point. But let me post the algorithm I had in mind. As I said, similar idea O(m+n), but w/o the reordering effect you are talking about.

Comment: Btw, I wasn't planning to post it because most of the people like one liners and don't care for performance. But once you shared your thoughts :)

Comment: @IvanStoev: You are right - people like one liners. Readability of code is very important. And at SO where multiple programers answer, it often becomes the difference between better answer and liked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient way to do that:

```
var countB = new Dictionary<string, int>(listB.Count);
foreach (var x in listB)
{
    int count;
    countB.TryGetValue(x, out count);
    countB[x] = count + 1;
}
listA.RemoveAll(x =>
{
    int count;
    if (!countB.TryGetValue(x, out count)) return false;
    if (count == 1)
        countB.Remove(x);
    else
        countB[x] = count - 1;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: You missed the step where you populate *countB*.

Comment: @displayName I did not - try and see (hint - the little line `countB[x] = count + 1;`) :)

Comment: Oh I see... didn't know about this behavior of `TryGetValue()` in dictionaries. Learned something new.